# Gulp minify all css/js and move to folder with same structure?

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify

I've this chrome extension that I'm working on, is there anyway i can minify all css and js and move to the build folder without losing the structure?

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('build/*', {read: false})
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/fonts/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/fonts'));
    gulp.src('assets/images/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'));
    gulp.src('_locales/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/_locales'));
    return gulp.src('src/manifest.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src('popup/*.html')
        .pipe(cleanhtml())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['jshint'], function() {
    gulp.src('/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/**/*.js'));
    return gulp.src(['/**/*.js', '!/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(stripdebug())
        .pipe(uglify({outSourceMap: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/**/*'));
});
```

currently this works for the css and other assets, but I cant figure out how to do it withe js as I have everything split up neatly in folders and components

Comment: I guess we need more info just than `move to the build folder without losing the structure?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check it rigt now, but I think you shoud do this:

1. Get rid of first two lines in your `scripts` task they do nothing as I see.
2. Fix `Task` method from gulp. It accepts only 2 parameters: `taskName` and `taskFunction`.
3. Fix `src`. As I understand you are saying `get all .js files, except all .js files` so nothing will be piped.
4. `gulp.dest` path shoul look like `build/` or `build/js/`.

Can you try this?

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(stripdebug())
        .pipe(uglify({outSourceMap: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'));
});
```